# Printing Title Tags of a Link in Python3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

Hi I'm  completely New to WebScraping in Python, what I want to do is to Print the Link Output to a Link Text Output.

Here's my Code as of Now:

```
try: 
    from googlesearch import search 

except ImportError:  
    print("No module named 'google' found") 

query = input("Enter your Search Query")
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2): 
    print(j)
```

I want the output variable j to be in the Form of the Link Text, not the Link.
Example, I want [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) as YouTube.

Comment: Offtop. Do you realize that in case of exception on line `from googlesearch import search` your code will fail on line `for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2)`? Why you added that `try`/`except`?

Comment: Please add the output you are currently getting to the question as readers may not be familiar with the output of the search() function. It looks like it may just requires a bit of string manipulation, probably using a regular expression. You could try looking up regular expressions in Python

Answer (score 0):

According to the source documentation below is the return for [search method](https://python-googlesearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#googlesearch.search):

**Returns:**
Generator (iterator) that yields found URLs.

So the function returns the URLs. You have to extract the text from the URL.